# How can I ignore a specific file while walking through the tree?

Tags: python, python-2.7, filenames, os.path

I want to ignore a specific file while using `os.walk(path)` to iterlate the subTree in the directory.

But for some reason, there is some file I am not expect to parse. e.g. the `.git` file which includes lots of documents. How can I do this?

```
 file_to_ignore = '.git'
 for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
     for filename in filenames:
         if filename == file_to_ignore: continue
         else: 
              #do somthing
```

Comment: `.git` is a *directory*, not a file.

Comment: you want to ignore the files inside the .git directory?

Comment: Use `dirnames[:] = [d for d in dirnames if d != '.git']` to remove that directory from consideration, see the duplicate as to why that works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `os` module to get extension of file by `os.path.splitext()` method.

Create ignore extension list if we want to add more ignore extension init

E.g.

True condition:

```
>>> import os
>>> filename = "abc.git"
>>> ignore = ['.git', ]
>>> os.path.splitext(filename)
('abc', '.git')
>>> os.path.splitext(filename)[1] in ignore
True
```

False condition:

```
>>> os.path.splitext("abc.txt")[1] in ignore
False
```